# Valid condition in blade form input

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

How to make valid condition for value tag in laravel 5.7 if field was modified and we have to show new value if field was modified ?
I tried like that with required condition :

```
(old('common_settings_site_name') ? old('common_settings_site_name') : ( isset($common_settings_site_name) ?$common_settings_site_name : '' ) ),
```

it is good, bur not n case when field with existing value was cleared, then original value(not old - clear) is shown.

Like text field had some text “Value”
The field was cleared.
submitting form original field would be shown not empty string as I exepected ?
How to fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: have you added required validation ?

Comment: Yes, with required condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at definition of old :

```
/**
     * Retrieve an old input item.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed   $default
     * @return mixed
     */
    function old($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        return app('request')->old($key, $default);
    }
```

You can use 2nd parameter for old method with your var.